# 'list indices must be integers, not tuple" in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am working on a python project ,i am unable to plot a graph with these values. I am not able to correct the error since i cant figure out the list which is throwing the error. i have provided the error below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

X = [[ 0.24459249,0.11983918,-0.85683004,-0.89438038,-0.50183492],
 [-0.7976035,1.95307959,-1.25068375,-0.00678967,-0.25262571],
 [ 0.34136607,0.92766956,0.66223556,-1.46454436,-1.60347224], 
 [ 2.22677877,1.55027737,-0.02381159,-0.05812014,0.17297636],
 [ 0.20753675,-1.00847549,-0.13858473,-0.93317858,0.18550176],
 [ 1.38946893,-1.03658362,-0.62923293,1.44856682,0.59064268]]

y = [ 0,2,1,0,0,0,3,0,2,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,
  0,0,0,0,1,3,4,0,0,0,0,3,0,2,1,0,0,0,
  3,1,3,0,4,0,0,0,1,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,
  1,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,2,2,1,0,2,1,0,3,
  1,1,1,0,1,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,3,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,2,1,
  2,3,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,0,3,2,3,4,0,3,1,0,
  3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,1,0,0,1,0,1,
  0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,1,1,1,2,0,0,4,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,4,1,0,1,0,0,
  3,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,1,2,0,3,1,2,0,3,0,0,
  0,1,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,0,1,0,4,0,3,1,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,3,2,0,2,1,0,
  0,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,1,3,0,0,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0,4,2,2,2,1,0,
  1,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,2,4,2,0,
  0,0,1,0,2,2,1,0,3,1,1,2,3,1,0]


def plot_2D(data, target, target_names):
     colors = cycle('rgbcmykw')
     target_ids = range(len(target_names))
     plt.figure()
 for i, c, label in zip(target_ids, colors, target_names):
     plt.scatter(data[target == i, 0], data[target == i, 1],
                c=c, label=label)
 plt.legend()
 plt.savefig('Reduced_PCA_Graph')



target_names = [0,1,2,3,4]
plot_2D(X, y, target_names)
```

ERROR IS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mat.py", line 49, in <module>
    plot_2D(X, y, target_names)
  File "mat.py", line 40, in plot_2D
    plt.scatter(data[target == i, 0], data[target == i, 1],
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: Please always include the full error traceback. That said, `X`, hence `data` is a list of lists. Fancy indexing like `data[target == i, 0]` only works on numpy-like array objects.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your dataset X and y please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe you want to have it that way:

```
def plot_2D(data, target, target_names):
    colors = cycle('rgbcmykw')
    target_ids = range(len(target_names))
    plt.figure()
    for i, c, label in zip(target_ids, colors, target_names):
        plt.scatter(data[target[i]][0], data[target[i]][1], c=c, label=label)
    plt.legend()
    #plt.savefig('Reduced_PCA_Graph')
    plt.show()
```